# How can I use LottieFiles to render animations?

Tags: 8

I created an [Lotti](https://lottiefiles.com/) animation and rendered it as a .json file. Is it possible to use this file in Drupal? Almost every other site builder from Squarespace to Webflow allows this file type of animation. Anyone have experience using it?

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting down voted but if you have a questions on what I asked, please comment so I can help clear things up if it isn't clear.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  It's probably you asking a broad question without providing much context or showing any effort of what you've tried yourself so far. Those questions usually get downvoted. Votes are anonymous. Maybe have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out more about the rules on this site.

Comment: Thank you! However, my question is pretty straight forward: can you add a Lottie file or .json file to your page? And if so, how do you go about doing it? I've searched all over but have not found anything useful. I know that you can call the .json file using a js script but I don't have much experience in Drupal to know what the capabilities are. The Lottie file (.json file) is an animation that is much smaller than a gif which is why I am looking to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is. See the LottiFiles [sample](https://lottiefiles.com/web-player?lottie_url=https%3A%2F%2Fassets4.lottiefiles.com%2Fpackages%2Flf20_32NcN8.json). **First**, you need to add the  Lotti player **library** yourself first.

```
https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js
```

Learn about adding [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme) in the docs.

And **second**, find a way to place the Lotti markup on the page somewhere.

```
<lottie-player 
    src="https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_32NcN8.json" 
    background="transparent"
    speed="1"
    style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"
    loop controls autoplay>
</lottie-player>
```

I'd probably have a field for that where you only paste the animation file URL or upload the animation file which then gets wrapped by the corresponding markup via a **custom field formatter**.

```
<lottie-player 
    src="{{ field_lotti.entity.url }}" 
    background="transparent"
    speed="1"
    style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"
    loop controls autoplay>
</lottie-player>
```

Comment: Amazing! I'll have a look and see if this is something they can use. Thank you so much!